# While copy pasting content into tiny mce editor it is redirected to login page

Tags: jquery

If we are copy pasting the following content.

TinyMCE 4.0.18, edit right here if you want

```
New user interface API
New modern skin!
Inline editing
Updated build process
Higher quality code
Reworked plugins
CDN support
And MUCH MUCH MORE!
```

---

twice means am facing this issue - Redirecting to login page in safari browser. Any one have solution. I need to fix this in jQuery.